# Angular Material Table Custom Filter Adding and Removing Multiple Terms

Tags: angular, filter, angular-material

I am implementing a custom filter using Angular's material-ui table and material-chips that involves being able to search data via match on multiple keywords.  The user should be able to add keywords and the table should filter appropriate matches, and the user should be able to remove any keywords as well and the table should display appropriate matches *after deleting keywords*

Here's the current implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-filter-with-chips

The filtering works when adding terms e.g. add `data` by pressing enter then add `science` filters down to one course, but removing `science` should return to two courses since only `data` remains as a keyword.

After removing a keyword, I simply try to apply the filter on the dataSource again with the remaining search terms (`this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.searchTerms);`) but the results do not update.

I've found [similar issues](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/12452) where the data-table is not being re-rendered properly after some update and they suggested resetting dataSource.data to trigger a new search on all the courses.

I've tried creating this clean reference as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849044/angular-material-mat-table-is-not-showing-updated-data-from-data-source/50849163), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885821/copying-of-an-array-of-objects-to-another-array-without-object-reference-in-java) and [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-cancelable-table-nxlib5?file=app%2Fcomponent%2Ftable.component.ts) but they don't seem to work in this case.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: added 2 tags & then removed one - then i went to the input, pressed a key and then pressed the backspace button... the whole data set became available as intended; you have correctly shown that dataSource had correct data, yet the results didn't "refresh" until i added and then removed a character from the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reset `globalFilter` inside your add method, otherwise you will filter the last inserted value together with the chip values.

You may set it to an empty string on your `add` method as bellow:

```
add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
  // ...
  this.globalFilter = '';
}
```