# How to Update Mat table view when data in the data source updates

Tags: node.js, angular, mat-table

I am Using Angular Mat Table to populate the data from database everything is working fine but the only issue is if some record in my database is updated,mat table does not update the view,i have to refresh the page  in order to view the changes in the record.I want A real time update using mat table is it possible?

Below Given is my code

```
dataSource: macDataSource;
this.dataSource = new macDataSource(this.MacService);
this.dataSource.loadMacs('', 'asc', 0, 10);

loadMacPage()

{
    this.dataSource.loadMacs(this.search_sims.nativeElement.value, this.sort.direction, this.paginator.pageIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
}


ngAfterViewInit()
{
    fromEvent(this.search_sims.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(tap(async () => {
        this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
        this.loadMacPage();

    })).subscribe();
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);
    merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page).pipe(tap(() => this.loadMacPage())).subscribe();
    this.ngx.stop();

}

export class macDataSource extends DataSource<MacModel[]>
{
    private macSubject = new BehaviorSubject<MacModel[]>([]);
    private loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    public loading$ = this.loadingSubject.asObservable();
    public macLength: any;
    public macData: any;
    constructor(private macService: MacService) {
        super();
    }
    connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<any> {
        return this.macSubject.asObservable();
    }

    disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
        this.macSubject.complete();
        this.loadingSubject.complete();
    }

    loadMacs(filter = '', sortDirection = 'asc', pageIndex = 0, pageSize = 10) {
        this.loadingSubject.next(true);
        this.macService.getAllmacs(filter, sortDirection, pageIndex, pageSize).pipe(catchError(() => of([])), finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false)))
            .subscribe(macs => { this.macSubject.next(macs); this.macLength = macs.length; this.macData = macs; this.loadingSubject.next(macs) });
    }

    getLength(): String {
        return this.macLength;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, it's possible ;)

Comment: how should i achieve that without using mongo streams

Comment: You need to show us your code and where you are facing an issue. No one can help otherwise.

Comment: How does your table get the data from the database?

Comment: @AJT_82 i have my code in the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Material mat-table is not showing updated data from data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849044/angular-material-mat-table-is-not-showing-updated-data-from-data-source)

Comment: @AkberIqbal not a duplicate i am asking about when data is updated in db not from some form

Comment: You need to trigger the change from the back-end so you probably need to serve the data changes through web sockets.

Comment: @SGalea how should i achieve that can you give me some link for understanding

Comment: Websockets on node https://flaviocopes.com/node-websockets/ angular material https://medium.com/@chainfrog/building-websockets-and-blockchain-into-angular-5-part-2-542335931506